# How to do inline shortcut for optional string assignment

Tags: swift

Is there something in swfit that is equivalent to the following in javascript?

```
optionalString = maybeThisExists || ""
myFunc(maybeThisExists || "")
```

In swfit should I do it this way?

```
myFunc(maybeThisExists ? maybeThisExists! : "")
```

Comment: In swift `??` (Nil Coalescing) done same thing...check out this guide...http://www.codingexplorer.com/nil-coalescing-swift/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `??` operator:

```
let optionalString = maybeThisExists ?? ""
```

`optionalString` will have the content of `maybeThisExists` if `maybeThisExists` is not nil, and otherwise it will get "".